# Turn Editing On in Moodle does not show

Tags: moodle

I have a moodle project and after updating to version 3.9 the turn editing on button is not shown, I can not edit my topics

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RTL themes in general but is it hidden in the cog menu (top left in your screenshot)?

If not, try the URL of your page, with &edit=on or &edit=off on the end of it - with Boost-based themes you can use the Boost Navigation Fumbling plugin (on the plugins directory) to add these links into your nav drawer for users with elevated access.